# DataTable is not a function in Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables

I want to implement datatables in my angular project. I have installed as stated in http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started .
But, it still is showing an error stating

> **DataTable is not a function**

This error usually occurs when we don't structure the **jQuery** file properly. But, I have structured it correctly and yet it is showing an error. Also, none of the options available in the datatables are getting displayed, only the plain text from the table.

[image]

Comment: How exactly are you using this library? You don't really need to use `$(...).DataTable` I guess. Is that something that you have written? Or is it the `lib` code. If possible, please create a stackblitz sample replicating your issue to work with.

Comment: Please look at [Basic examples](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/with-options) in documentation. You're not supposed to call `.DataTables()` function on your elements. You have to use the provided directives: `<table datatable [dtOptions]="optionsDeclaredInController" >...</table>`

Comment: even i am facing the same issue. As suggested i am using the datatables directive and no explicit declaring or initializing of Datatables is written in code.